# Accessing a row in Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid view in which there is a repeater I want to get the id of child comment but this is giving me parent comment id

```
protected void rChildComments_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Button btnDeleteChildComment = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnDeleteChildComment");

    if (e.CommandName == "DeleteChildComment")
    {
        Control c = e.Item.NamingContainer.Parent;

       // Guid mcID = new Guid(e.Item.Cells[0].Text);
        //MemberFacade.DeleteMemberPublicChildComments(mcID);
        //Response.Redirect("profile.aspx" + "?mid=" + ProfileID);

        DataGridItem DgItems = (DataGridItem)c.NamingContainer;
        string text = DgItems.Cells[0].Text;
    }
}
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to find Child Comment Control like that

```
DgItems.FindContol
```